# How can I hide the back button from certain pages in the shell?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

Only on the `login` and `notifications` pages I wish that the user could not return to the previous page. On all other pages the process can proceed normally.

So far, I've only been able to disable the button click action using `BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled = "False"`.

**NotificationsPage.xaml** and **LoginPage.xaml**

```xml
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled="False"/>
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

[image: Back arrow button visible in navigation bar]

**TokenViewModel**

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(NotificacoesPage)}");
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(NotificacoesPage)}", false);
```

**AppShell.xaml**

```xml
<TabBar>
        <Tab Icon="notificacao_icone.png"
             Title="Notificações">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NotificacoesPage}" />
        </Tab>

        <Tab Icon="configuracoes_icone.png"
             Title="Configurações">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ConfiguracoesPage}" />
        </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

**AppShell.xaml.cs**

```cs
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LoginPage), typeof(LoginPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TokenPage), typeof(TokenPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(NotificacoesPage), typeof(NotificacoesPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(NotificacaoDetalhePage), typeof(NotificacaoDetalhePage));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ConfiguracoesPage), typeof(ConfiguracoesPage));
```

Comment: After the user fills in the `login` fields and fills in the `token` field, he is directed to the `notifications` page (the one on the print). Through the lower menu he can access the `settings` page where he can delete his account (this will take him to the `login` page to fill in the fields again).

Comment: Both using gotoasync

Comment: Would [modal navigation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-shell-quick-tip-modal-navigation/) suit you?

Comment: This is a known  [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11404) and it had been moved to the [to do block](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/projects/54#card-41801039).

Comment: @Shaw I will not be able to use modal navigation because I need to display the app's logo in `Shell.TitleView`.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I commented on the issue but apparently without any resolution right.

Comment: Well, fake a title view there

Comment: Use `TitleView` other than `Shell`? How would the property be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround.You could hide the whole navigationbar,then custom a NavigationBar with StackLayout to instead of it.

Something like:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ShellNewDemo.Views.ItemDetailPage"
         Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"   //hide the navigationbar
         >

  <ContentPage.Content>

      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

            //define your custom navigationbar

        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

           //content

        </StackLayout>

      </StackLayout>
    
  </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```